# use mfglabs commons-aws-sqs and dwhjames library without bintray

Tags: scala, amazon-sqs, bintray

I have a service that uses mfglabs, commons-aws-sqs in Scala, and dwhjames.

Those libraries were hosted on bintray, which was sunset few weeks ago.

What is the best solution to solve this?

Are there any other solutions? Or a solution that will enable me to keep use those libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that the libraries were open source, you can build them yourself.  That said, if their maintainers haven't moved them to other artifact hosts, that might be an indication that the libraries are abandoned.